# Validating in-code-message-age at compile time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

We allow to programmer to add a `TODO` message to code. Every time the file is compiled, message is written to the output (via pragma message). The `TODO` is a macro, containing a message and date when it was created. E.g. `TODO(3, 8, 2015, "...");`

I want to validate that no `TODO` is older than 30 days (roughly) and prevent compilation if there is such. (you can of course change date, but it will be clearly visible in version control)

I need solution, which works in MS VC 2012

I have written (based on [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424382/get-current-month-index-in-compile-time)) a version, which works fine on gcc - [Here is working example](http://ideone.com/PBqKOJ)
but it doesn't compile on visual studio with `error C2057 : expected constant expression` message

```
#define TOTAL_DAYS(day,month,year) (day + month*31 + year*365)

namespace checkingDate
{
#define C(i) static const char c##i = __DATE__[i];

    C(0); C(1); C(2); C(3);
    C(4); C(5); C(6); C(7);
    C(8); C(9); C(10);

    static const int current_date = c4 == ' ' ? c5 - '0' : c5 - '0' + 10;

    static const int current_month = (
        c0 == 'J' // Jan Jun Jul
        ? (c1 == 'a' ? 1 : (c2 == 'n' ? 6 : 7))
        : c0 == 'F' ? 2
        : c0 == 'M' // Mar May
        ? (c2 == 'r' ? 3 : 5)
        : c0 == 'A' // Apr Aug
        ? (c1 == 'p' ? 4 : 8)
        : c0 == 'S' ? 9
        : c0 == 'O' ? 10
        : c0 == 'N' ? 11
        : 12
        );

    static const int current_year = ((c7 - '0') * 1000) + ((c8 - '0') * 100) + ((c9 - '0') * 10) + (c10 - '0');
    static const int totalDays = TOTAL_DAYS(current_date, current_month, current_year);
}

#   define TODO(day,month,year, str)  static_assert(checkingDate::totalDays - TOTAL_DAYS(day,month,year)<30, "old msg");

int main()
{
    TODO(3, 8, 2015, "...");
}
```

Can I somehow fix this error? 
Is it my error or MS VC bug?
Is there other way to write it, so it works in visual studio?

Comment: what line does msvc give you the bug at?

Comment: on TODO(3, 8, 2015, "..."); where static_assert is

Comment: I don't have msvc so I can't check, but I would assume that if you do the arithmetic using templates it would work in msvc since that is an older feature than the static_assert, constexpr stuff.

Comment: This boils down to to the fact that `__DATE__[i]` isn't accepted as constant expression by VS2012. Even `"Sep 6 2015"[0]` isn't taken as constant expression. And there seems to be no way of processing strings with the preprocessor.